# SVG, D3: Understanding stop offset attribute

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, linear-gradients

I was trying to understand the offset attribute of 'stop' svg element but couldn't get my head around it. Here's the code:

```
var vis = d3.select(scalecontainer)
            .append("svg")
            .attr('height', 30)

var gradient = vis.append("linearGradient")
                    .attr("y1", 0)
                    .attr("y2", 0)
                    .attr("x1", "0%")
                    .attr("x2", "100%")
                    .attr("id", "gradient")
                    .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")

gradient
    .append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "0%")
    .attr("stop-color", "red")

gradient
    .append("stop")
    .attr("offset","33%")
    .attr("stop-color", "yellow")

gradient
    .append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "66%")
    .attr("stop-color", "green")

var rect = vis.append("rect")
            .attr("x", 10)
            .attr("y", 10)
            .attr("width", 100)
            .attr("height", 20)
            .attr("fill", "url(#gradient)");
```

And here's the output that I get:

[image]

Shouldn't there be 3 different evenly spaced colour variations of 'red', 'yellow', and 'green'? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: if there is still a problem, please comment on my answer so that I can improve it. If my answer solved your problem, feel free to accept it ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 3 different evenly spaced colour variatoins, but your `rect` has only an width of 100px whereas the `linearGradient` has the width of the `svg` element.
Set the two widths equally and your gradient will be fully visible.

The easiest way to get the full gradient inside your rect would be to set `.attr("gradientUnits", "objectBoundingBox")`. That way your gradient will be scaled to fit inside the element that references to the gradient.
A detailed explanation of all possible settings can be read on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/gradientUnits).

Comment: @Tarun I updated my answer, did this help you? Or is there still something unclear to you?